# What is the need to say a full "sentence"?

Tags: tense, definition

Definition of **Tense:**

> Tense is the **form** that a **verb** takes to show the time it happened.

So if someone ask me to give an example of *the present tense* can I answer with the **basic from of a verb** eg, *be, play, work etc.* instead of saying a *full sentence* like: *I play football every day?*

Likewise, an example of the **past tense** is **played**, not **I played football yesterday?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends who is asking and the full scope of the question, but I would avoid giving single word answers.

Here is my reasoning:

> "I am playing football" is present continuous tense.
>
> "I play football every day" is simple present tense.
>
> "I will play football tomorrow" is future tense.
>
> "I have played football 3 times this week" is present perfect tense

Notice that in these 4 examples, 2 have the same word "play" but they are two different tenses and then one looks as if it's past, but it's present perfect.

I could go on with examples of the different forms, but I think you get the idea! It's not a one-word-fits-all senario.

Here is a good source to look at: [The English Space](https://www.theenglishspace.com/grammar/tenses/)